# in vb.net is it possible to use a validator to limit the words allowed to be entered

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

in vb.net is it possible to use a validator to limit the words allowed to be entered. The words that can only be entered are "house" "flat" "semi" "duplex" for text box called housetype

Comment: Then why you need textbox? Go for dropdown then.

Answer (score 1):

You have many possibilities. One option would be to create a list of the words to allow and use the [List.Any extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like this:

```
dim words as new List(of string) From { "house", "flat", "semi", "duplex" }
dim word = housetype.Text
Console.WriteLine(words.Any (function(w) w = word))
```

This has the advantage, that it is easily extensible if new words should come (or if the list is read from a configuration file, and so on).

The functionaility could be packed in an extension method in order to make the code more readable, something like `if (texBoxControl.ContainsOnlyValidWords()) then ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better solution then SkorrloreGaming-Productions's answer...

```
 Public Function CheckForAllowedWords() As String
        Dim ok_word As String
        Dim AllowedWords As String() = "house flat semi duplex".Split(" ")
        For Each item As String In AllowedWords
            If housetype.Text = item Then
                ok_word = item
                Exit For
            Else
                Continue For
            End If
        Next
        Return ok_word
    End Function
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CheckForAllowedWords()
        If CheckForAllowedWords() <> Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Accepted")
        Else
            MsgBox("Not Accepted")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: .contains - then you don't need to faff around with an array